# Extract the first n chunks of a string within a data frame column

Tags: r, stringr, rowwise

I have a dataframe column containing strings made up of several "chunks" divided by separators, as in: XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX. I want to make a new column that contains the first N chunks, i.e. XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX for N = 4.

I can do this using `tidyr::separate()`:

```
df %>% separate(col1, into = c('tmp1', 'tmp2', 'tmp3', 'tmp4'), sep = '-', remove = F) %>%
       mutate(col2 = paste(tmp1, tmp2, tmp2, sep = '-')
```

But I'd like a more direct way that avoids making the temp columns. I have a partial solution using `stringr::str_split`:

```
df %>% mutate(col2 = paste(str_split(col1, '-')[[1]][1:4], collapse = '-'))
```

This works for a single string, but it doesn't vectorise properly—when applied to a dataframe, every line has the same col2. This comes from the `[[1]]`, because if I change it to `[[2]]` then every line of col2 corresponds to row #2 of col1. I tried using `[[row_number()]]`, but that gave me the error `"recursive indexing failed at level 2"`. Does anyone know how to vectorise this along a dataframe, ideally with `mutate()` rather than `apply()`?

Answer (score 0):

Typing this all out helped me figure out the answer, so in case it's helpful to anyone...Just add `rowwise()` before the `mutate()` and it works perfectly.

```
df %>% 
rowwise() %>%
mutate(col2 = paste(str_split(col1, '-')[[1]][1:4], collapse = '-'))
```